# How to get rid of this footer from the ACM template?

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, acm

How can I remove the footer as is included in the ACM double column template? I created a screenshot of it: http://cdn.imghack.se/images/223c46062e6b28d6b0d9dc9500bf6098.jpg

A minmal file producing this footer looks like this:

```
\documentclass{acmtog}

\acmVolume{28}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmYear{2009}
\acmMonth{September}
\acmArticleNum{106}
\acmdoi{10.1145/1559755.1559763}

\begin{document}
\title{a}
\author{a}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

When I remove the following lines...

```
\acmVolume{28}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmYear{2009}
\acmMonth{September}
\acmArticleNum{106}
\acmdoi{10.1145/1559755.1559763}
```

..then I get errors. I'm a beginner and confused why the template or more precisely the .cls file demands this information. I mean shouldn't it be possible to compile without having an ACM article number for example?

The respective .cls file is from http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/ (v2-acmtog.zip)

Comment: Those are supposed to be added by the editorial office, not the authors. Anyway, how about removing the content, rather than the command. i.e, use \acm...{} instead.

Comment: This leaves punctuation in the footer.

Comment: Instead of useless code snippets, please compose a simple, but *complete* document illustrating the problem and add it as an edit to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended you by the format of my question. I did now knew it was malformed. I will update the question as soon I find the time to do so.

Comment: Added a complete document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `acmtog` class is not intended to be used without the footer. However, the following works:

```
\documentclass{acmtog}

% clear acmtog.cls footer settings
\makeatletter
\def\runningfoot{\def\@runningfoot{}}
\def\firstfoot{\def\@firstfoot{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{a}
\author{a}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works marvelously. An offtopic question of mine would be how this is handled then with submissions of papers i.e. what do authors put into the footer when they submit a paper for review? Or do they get all necessary information that go into the footer before review?

Answer (score 0):

I came across a recent issue and one way I overcame this by defining a new macro in the preamble of my main latex document.

Here is an example of how it would look:

```
\documentclass{sigchi}

\makeatletter
\def\@copyrightspace{\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This command worked in the latest(March2018) version of the ACM SIGCHI template as well as when using the 2015 ACM `sig-alternate` class file.